# Which kernel version has the TDX (Trust Domain Extensions) feature supported?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, intel

I would like to know about the kernel version having the TDX (Trust Domain Extensions) feature supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-TDX-For-Linux-5.19) no released kernels support this feature. Linux 5.19 will be released approximately in three months.